# storing technique in sql

Tags: database-design

I have a Groups and in them I have users,
how should I store them in Database?

1. one way I  thought of is store all the groups in one main table and the users in the secondary table that holds all the group's users, but the downside that I will need to open a table for each group.
2. another way is using a json like format to store the users in column users in the main Group table.
3. another way is using  2 tables one for the group and another one will hold the columns: group, user.  but in this format i fear there will be lots of duplicated data and I want to be efficient.

for exmple:

Users [user1, user2, user3]

groups[group1, group2, group3]

in group1 user1 and user2 are members.

thank you for reading and helping!

Comment: Welcome to SO. You do not store data in SQL but in tables in  database.  I have changed tag to database design.

Comment: Could you please add sample data in post. It will be helpful in answering your question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need three tables:
1) table for your groups
2) table for your users
3) table with for a n:m-relation with two columns: group_id and user_id

Answer (score 0):

The canonical, correct SQL way is your third suggestion, a n:m mapping table between users and groups. There's nothing inefficient about that, and you won't have duplicate data in there. (Just make sure to set up an unique constraint on the `(group_id, user_id)` tuples.)

Having that table will also make it trivial to query e.g. all the groups an user belongs to, or all users in a list of groups, etc.